# My Discord bot won't reply back with the Embed I made

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, discord, discord.js

I don't know much about coding myself but I followed someone's video (specifically this video:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tQjpv0OO5pA) on how to make embeds on discord using your own bot and I did what he showed on the video... It was outdated but there were people in the comment section helping each other out... But it didn't help me that much because I had the ***same problem all over again which is the embeds not showing up when I enter my prefix*** **(which is !embed)** even though I don't get any errors in visual studio code.

[image]

Comment: It seems as though you didn't define `discord`. Try replacing that with `Discord`

Comment: You've leaked your token! You should never, ever give out the token to anyone or post it on sites like SO. You should regenerate it now before someone takes advantage of it.

Comment: My bad hahaha thanks for letting me bro I'll be careful next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you try replacing the `switch` statements with the following :-

```
//write instead of switch

if (message.content === `${prefix}embed`) {
    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
       .setTitle("test")
       .setDescription("Test");
    message.channel.send(embed);
}
```

Comment: I get a SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'

Comment: @Kire Do you have discord, we can talk there